# Styling issue on safari - working fine on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I have a styling issue. Everything looks great on other browsers, but on safari there is a file input box behaving really strange. See the images below:

Opened with Safari:

[image: Opened with Safari]

Opened with Chrome (how is is supposed to look):

[image: Opened with Chrome (how is is supposed to look]

CSS:

```
.fileInput {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
}
.chat {
    height: 80%;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #DDD;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

All hints and guesses are much appreciated.

Comment: What is different, the text inside the input field? Can you provide some more code or a link so we can help you?

Comment: The text in Safari means "Nothing chosen" - which is fine. However, it is placed quite far above the "vælg arkiv"- button. You can see it on fanpuls.com. You just need to make a user first or just login which
Email: hello@hej.dk, Password: 1234